# How to add table column headings to sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, header

I have a SQL select statement like this:

```
select FirstName, LastName, Age from People
```

This will return me something like a table:

```
Peter  Smith    34
John   Walker   46
Pat    Benetar  57
```

What I want is to insert the column headings into the first row like:

```
First Name  Last Name  Age
=========== ========== ====
Peter       Smith      34
John        Walker     46
Pat         Benetar    57
```

Can someone suggest how this could be achieved?

Could you maybe create a temporary table with the headings and append the data one to this?

Comment: If you want to add a header to EVERY column including NON-VARCHAR columns, you have many problems with this approach (if you insist on the database layer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither of the answers above will work, unless all your names come after "first" in sort order.

```
Select FirstName, LastName
from (
    select Sorter = 1, FirstName, LastName from People
    union all
    select 0, 'FirstName', 'LastName') X
order by Sorter, FirstName   -- or whatever ordering you need
```

If you want to do this to all non-varchar columns as well, the CONS are (at least):

1. ALL your data will become VARCHAR.  If you use Visual Studio for example, you will NO LONGER be able to recognize or use date values.  Or int values. Or any other for that matter.
2. You need to explicitly provide a format to datetime values like DOB.  DOB values in Varchar in the format dd-mm-yyyy (if that is what you choose to turn them into) won't sort properly.

The SQL to achieve this, however **not-recommended**, is

```
Select FirstName, LastName, Age, DOB
from (
    select Sorter = 1,
        Convert(Varchar(max), FirstName) as FirstName,
        Convert(Varchar(max), LastName)  as LastName,
        Convert(Varchar(max), Age)       as Age,
        Convert(Varchar(max), DOB, 126)  as DOB
    from People
    union all
    select 0, 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age', 'DOB') X
order by Sorter, FirstName   -- or whatever ordering you need
```

Comment: @cyberwiki: yes, i failed with `UNION ALL`. In some reason I though it takes unique values from different sets only. Thanks.

Comment: +1 @cyberkiwi: good point to mention possible problem when it comes to ordering

Answer (score 3):

The lightest-weight way to do this is probably to do a UNION:

```
SELECT 'FirstName' AS FirstName, 'LastName' AS LastName
UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName 
FROM People
```

No need to create temporary tables.

Comment: You won't be able to tell if 'FirstName' is a name, since it is sorted anywhere in the data.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: there is no `order by` - so `UNION ALL` will just append second result set to the first one.

Comment: Hi, good answer. I made my question example too simplified though. Turns out one of the columns isn't of string type ie. Age so they seem to clash when you union. Is there a way round that? Have modified the question now.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I tried, but in oracle ;-) And it appears right after the first set ;-)

Comment: @Coder 2: `select 'column A', 'column B' union all select cast(col1 as varchar(255)), col2 from table`

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION All` is the solution except it should be pointed out that:

1. To add a header to a non-char column will require converting the column in the first part of the query.
2. If the converted column is used as part of the sort order then the field reference will have to be to the name of the column in the query, not the table

example:

```
Select Convert(varchar(25), b.integerfiled) AS [Converted Field]...
... Order by [Converted Field]
```