# Adding columns to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

What i have right now is a stored procedure which have a sql statement that produces the result below.

```
| Name | Lastname | Age | Gender | <- Columns
|Robert|   Bob    | 30  |  Male  | <- Row1
```

What i am trying to do from here is to get the columns and place them on the first row. For example

```
| Name | Lastname | Age | Gender | <- Columns
| Name | Lastname | Age | Gender | <- Row1
|Robert|   Bob    | 30  |  Male  | <- Row2
```

How can i accomplish this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964162/how-to-add-table-column-headings-to-sql-select-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to `UNION` it...

```
SELECT
   'LastName',
   'FirstName',
   'Age',
   'Gender'
UNION ALL
SELECT
   LastName,
   FirstName,
   Age,
   Gender
FROM YourTable
```

Note that the columns specified in the second select all have to be `nvarchar` in this case otherwise you'll probably get a conversion error.