# Return column names of mysql query

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a MySQL query that is exported as a CSV file. The person who receives the CSV wants me to include the column headings. Obviously I can hard code them in the query but wondered if there was a way to return a row that has the names of all of the columns that have been queried?

My current query is below - I wish to programatically include the column headings too if I can just in case I forget to update it when changes are made.

Thanks

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
   "SELECT
        cf_id as FoundUsFrom,
        firstname as CustomerName1,
        lastname as CustomerName2,
        address1 as CAddress1,
        address2 as CAddress2,
        '' as CAddress3,
        towncity as CCity,
        postcode as CPostCode,
        email as 'email',
        telephone as HomePhone,
        mobile as MobilePhone,
        '' as WorkPhone,
        chidname as PName,
        '' as ToBeAged,
        partyaddress1 as PAddress1,
        partyaddress2 as PAddress2,
        '' as PAddress3,
        partytowncity as PCity,
        partypostcode as PPostCode,
        /*NEED VALIDATION*/
        celebrating as PType,
        partydate as PDate,
        partyboffinstart as PTime,
        specialinstructions as SpecialInst,
        numberguests as Guests,
        IF(airexp = '','N','Y') as Air,
        IF(chemcocklngexp = '','N','Y') as CocktailLong,
        IF(chemcockshtexp = '','N','Y') as CocktailShort,
        IF(chemreact = '','N','Y') as Reactions,
        IF(dryicebolton = '','N','Y') as DryIce,
        IF(electricitybolton = '','N','Y') as Electricity,
        IF(flightbolton = '','N','Y') as Flight,
        IF(fourelementsbolton = '','N','Y') as Elements,
        IF(magicbolton = '','N','Y') as Magic,
        IF(slimebolton = '','N','Y') as Slime,
        IF(sweetbolton = '','N','Y') as Sweets,
        IF(miniimpsbolton = '','N','Y') as MiniImps,
        IF(extravaganzabolton = '','N','Y') as Extravaganza,
        IF(dryicecreambolton = '','N','Y') as AIceCream,
        IF(rocketbolton = '','N','Y') as ARocket,
        IF(foodbreakbolton = '','N','Y') as AFood,
        partybags as PBags,
        deluxepartybags as PDBags

INTO OUTFILE 'PATHTO/data/bookings",
DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d%s'),
".csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM sb_chronoforms_data_bookingformcombined"
);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Comment: You can use union ;) to return column names in first row

Comment: This might help [How to add table column headings to sql select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964162/how-to-add-table-column-headings-to-sql-select-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loging this separately since it's another way to solve the issue:

> select 'col_1', 'col_2','col_3','col_4' from dual UNION all select
>   col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 from table_1;

Answer (score 0):

that's a strange question :) try

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS
where
    table_chema = 'your_schema'
        and table_name = 'your_table';
```

than use **ordinal_position** to display the relevant column name